# Lower Part of Expanded TaskDialog Form Goes Offscreen

Tags: forms, autohotkey, taskdialog

The problem occurs when the `hWndParent` is positioned near the taskbar at the base of the screen. Clicking `pszExpandedInformation` extends the TaskDialog form below offscreen instead of moving the newly sized form up screen to show the expanded details.
The [TASKDIALOGCONFIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taskdialogconfig) structure is filled for 64bit in the following test code accordingly, click "See Details" to submerge:

```
Gui, testGui: New, -MaximizeBox -MinimizeBox +OwnDialogs +LastFound
testGuiW := floor(A_ScreenWidth/6)
testGuiH := floor(A_ScreenHeight/9)

Gui, testGui: Add, Button, center Default w%testGuiW% h%testGuiH% gRunTaskDialog vTaskDlg, Run TaskDialog
Gui, testGui: Default 
GuiControl, testGui: Move, TaskDlg, x%testGuiW% y%testGuiH%

testGuiW := floor(A_ScreenWidth/2)
testGuiH := floor(A_ScreenHeight/3)


Gui, testGui: Show, % "y" . A_ScreenHeight - testGuiH . " w" . testGuiW . " h" . testGuiH
Return


RunTaskDialog:
retVal := TaskDialog("Test", "Test Issue", "", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,`nconsectetur adipiscing elit,`nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.`nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,`nsunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", , "Close Test")
Return

Esc::
testGuiGuiClose:
ExitApp


; Task dialog
TaskDialog(pageTitle := "Page Title", instructionTitle := "Description of issue", description := "Choose one of the following options:", expandedText := "More Information with a <A HREF=""http://www.some_link.com"">Link</a>", checkText := "Do not show this again", choice1 := "", choice2 := "", choice3 := "", choice4 := "")
{
; This function requires A_Unicode and Vista or later.
Static FooterText := ""
; Error Flags
Static S_OK = 0x0, E_OUTOFMEMORY = 0x8007000E, E_INVALIDARG = 0x80070057, E_FAIL = 0x80004005, E_ACCESSDENIED = 0x80070005

;General Flags
Static flags = 0x1011, TDF_VERIFICATION_FLAG_CHECKED = 0x0100, TDF_CALLBACK_TIMER := 0X0800

; 0x1   :       TDF_ENABLE_HYPERLINKS
; 0X0010:       TDF_USE_COMMAND_LINKS
; 0x1000:       TDF_POSITION_RELATIVE_TO_WINDOW 
; 0x1000000:    TDF_SIZE_TO_CONTENT

CustomButtons := []

hwndParent := WinExist("A")

    if (!(TDCallback := RegisterCallback("TDCallback", "Fast")))
    {
        MsgBox, 8208, Task Dialog, Could not Register Callback for the Task dialog.
        return 0
    }

    While (tp := choice%A_Index%)
    CustomButtons.Push(100 + A_Index, tp)


cButtons := CustomButtons.Length()/2
VarSetCapacity(pButtons, 4 * cButtons + A_PtrSize * cButtons, 0)

    loop %cButtons%
    {
    iButtonID := CustomButtons[2 * A_Index -1]
    iButtonText := &(b%A_Index% := CustomButtons[2 * A_Index])
    NumPut(iButtonID,   pButtons, (4 + A_PtrSize) * (A_Index - 1), "Int")
    NumPut(iButtonText, pButtons, (4 + A_PtrSize) * A_Index - A_PtrSize, "Ptr")
    }


; TASKDIALOGCONFIG structure
    if (A_PtrSize == 8) ; X64
    {
    NumPut(VarSetCapacity(TDC, 160, 0), TDC, 0, "UInt") ; cbSize
    NumPut(hwndParent, TDC, 4, "Ptr") ; hwndParent
    ;  HINSTANCE
    NumPut(flags, TDC, 20, "Int") ; dwflags
    NumPut(&pageTitle, TDC, 28, "Ptr") ; pszWindowTitle
    NumPut(&instructionTitle, TDC, 44, "Ptr") ; pszMainInstruction
    NumPut(&description, TDC, 52, "Ptr") ; pszContent
    NumPut(cButtons, TDC, 60, "UInt") ; cButtons
    NumPut(&pButtons, TDC, 64, "Ptr") ; pButtons
    NumPut(&checkText, TDC, 92, "Ptr") ; pszVerificationText
    NumPut(&ExpandedText, TDC, 100, "Ptr") ; pszExpandedInformation
    NumPut(&FooterText, TDC, 132, "Ptr") ; pszFooter
    NumPut(TDCallback, TDC, 140, "Ptr") ; pfCallback
    }
    else
    return

retVal := DllCall("Comctl32.dll\TaskDialogIndirect", "Ptr", &TDC
    , "Int*", Button := 0
    , "Int*", Radio := 0
    , "Int*", Checked := 0)

; various error checks omitted for brevity  

return retVal
}
TDCallback(hWnd, Notification, wParam, lParam, RefData)
{
Static TDE_FOOTER = 0X0002, TDM_UPDATE_ELEMENT_TEXT := 0x400 + 114, TDM_CLICK_BUTTON := 0x400 + 102, timeOut := 10
    switch (Notification)
    {
        Case 3:
        {
        url := StrGet(lParam, "UTF-16") ; <A HREF="URL">Link</A>
        Run %url%
        }
        Default:
    }
}
```

Is there any way to reposition the form so that the lower y co-ordinates before and after expanding remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

The controls of the *TaskDialog* (apart from the `Continue` button) aren't easily accessible. The other controls identify as [directuihwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089196/netuihwnd-and-directuihwnd) and their click events aren't available other than through the callback. In this case it's [TDM_UPDATE_ELEMENT_TEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tdm-update-element-text), even so, we have [no control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68167683/2128797) over the (changing the) dimensions of the Taskdialog.
Thus the obvious solution is to not specify the `hwndParent` in the `TDC` structure whenever the expando button is used, which consequently repositions the *TaskDialog* in the centre of the screen.

Also, the docs state:

> The parent window should not be hidden or disabled when this function is called

Instead, a transient cloaked window as a parent situated somewhere above the original parent as a test candidate?

Edit: According to  @Remy Lebeau's post at this [forum](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4319-can-the-width-of-taskmessagedlg-be-set/?tab=comments#comment-37635) it's possible with a hook on the [TDN_DIALOG_CONSTRUCTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tdn-dialog-constructed) message to obtain the handle of the dialog, thereby facilitating the move of the form on the `wParam` of `TDM_UPDATE_ELEMENT_TEXT`. The windows event hook might be better for this- there is an implementation [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=830) for it.

**Edit2**:
Turns out the window *can* be moved to some specified co-ordinate, unfortunately for the bottom edges to match, the precise ordinate cannot be determined until expando clicked. An estimate of the height can be determined by the number of lines in the expanded text, presumably the font is MS Sans Serif but the size could vary according to various system settings. For the example in the question, replace the callback function with the following to move the dialog up by its height factor:

```
    TDCallback(hWnd, Notification, wParam, lParam, RefData)
{
Static tdYpos := 0, tdHeight
Static TDN_CREATED := 0, TDN_HYPERLINK_CLICKED := 3, TDN_EXPANDO_BUTTON_CLICKED := 10
    switch (Notification)
    {
        Case TDN_CREATED:
        {
        VarSetCapacity(rect, 16, 0)

            if (DllCall("GetWindowRect", "Ptr", hWnd, "Ptr", &rect))
            tdYpos := NumGet(rect, 4, "int")
            tdHeight := NumGet(rect, 12, "int") - tdYpos

        VarSetCapacity(rect, 0)
        }
        Case TDN_HYPERLINK_CLICKED:
        {
        url := StrGet(lParam, "UTF-16") ; <A HREF="URL">Link</A>
        Run %url%
        }

        Case TDN_EXPANDO_BUTTON_CLICKED:
        winmove ahk_id %hWnd%, , , % (wParam?A_ScreenHeight - 2*tdHeight: tdYpos)
        Default:
    }
}
```

**Edit3**: A move of the dialog with improved precision is posted at [this thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=101676).

Comment: As a matter of interest, moving the parent in the `TDN_EXPANDO_BUTTON_CLICKED` message in the callback with something like `winmove ahk_id %hwndParent%, , , % A_ScreenHeight - 2 * testGuiH` will not alter the position of the TaskDialog in successive expando clicks.